# Sharepoint: Create a task for 2 users and continue workflow if just one aprove the task

Tags: designer-workflow

I do not know if it's possible but I need in a workflow create a task for 2 users and if only 1 of them approve the flow should continue. The problem so far is that he always waits for the approval of the 2 to continue the workflow.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [Multiple approvers with only one approval reqired](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c612c055-6eeb-45bd-ab15-65ab94386b3b/multiple-approvers-with-only-one-approval-reqired?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy):

> If you use the Out of the Box Approval workflow you can specify in a parallel workflow how many approvals need to be entered for the item to be approved.  If you enter 2 approver addresses and set it up so that approval only needs one then it will be approved when the first person approves it.  Workflow tasks for all other workflow instances on the item will be cancelled.  I don't remember the exact name of the setting but its toward the bottom of the Initiation form that comes up when you configure the workflow on a document libary.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for the answer but i can't find that setting you mentioned. Can you check the right name? Thanks again.